# Why can any language in NP run on a P machine?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, np, turing-machines

How can I show that any language in NP can also be run on a P machine? I get that the resulting time wouldn't be polynomial.

Is it because any problem in NP can be solved by trying every possible combination which can be solved on a Polynomial turing machine? I find it very hard to come up with a solid real argument.

Thanks <|:-)

Comment: What is a P machine?

Comment: Probably a polynomial time turing machine @btilly

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question. It is a question about the theory of computation, not a practical computer program.

Comment: @Caspertijmen1 In that case, the correct terminology is [non-deterministic turing machine versus a deterministic turning machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_Turing_machine#Deterministic_Turing_machine).

Comment: First, you need to prove P=NP. (Sorry, the proof is too large to for into the comment section.) Then it follows that every problem in NP can be solved by a deterministic Turing Machine in polynomial time.

Comment: If a problem is in NP, then solutions have proofs that can be checked on a normal Turing machine in polynomial time.  There is therefore a polynomial bound on the size of the required proof, and a Turing machine can generate and test all possible proofs of that size or less.  It'll just take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. Firstly, a language (or equivalently, a decision problem) cannot "run" on a Turing Machine. A problem may be *solved* by a Turing Machine. Secondly, what is a "P Machine"? Do you mean a deterministic Turing Machine that terminates after a number of steps that is polynomial with respect to its input?

I can imagine two possible interpretations of your statement.

#### Every problem in NP can be solved by a deterministic Turing Machine in polynomial time

This is actually an open problem. To prove this, you first prove the P=NP. Once you have done that, congratulations for becoming a Millenium Price winner, and the statement to be proven follows immediately.

#### Every problem in NP can be solved by a deterministic Turing Machine

Now this is a much weaker statement. We can prove a much stronger and more interesting statement that implies this statement: Every non-deterministic Turing Machine can be simulated by a deterministic Turing Machine.

The proof roughly goes like this: the computation of a non-deterministic Turing Machine on some input can be represented as a computation tree. The simulating machine traverses this tree using a breadth-first search approach (basically using a queue of configurations). The machine stops when it finds a configuration with accepting state or if the tree has been traversed completely. Formalizing this simulation is tedious but possible, but I hope this gives you an intuition why it is possible.